# How to awk only output-lines containing a keyword?

Tags: shell-script, awk, browser

I am in the process of writing a small script, which checks browser-tabs on certain keywords. If the keyword is present, then the script closes the tab. The script is actually a simple "block-site" script for every browser, as long as the browser is supported in the python-programm ["brotab"](https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab) by Yuri Bochkarev. Way more secure then installing browser-addons.

My first line of code which worked was

```
bt list | grep keyword > tmp-file; cut -c 1-7 < tmp-file | bt close
```

But this code doesn't meet the KISS requirement and actually is faulty, because the TAB-ID does not always contain exactly seven characters.

Therfore I learned some AWK and - thanks [to this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1107681/1270261) - came up with the following command

```
bt list | awk -F "[\t]" '/keyword/{print$1}'
```

this works now!

for other newbies:
-F specifies the field seperator and \t sets it to be a tabulator.
{print$1} tells awk to ouput only the first field.

Second question: I want to block more than one keyword. I thought about using a keywords-file. Whats the best practise for that? I thought about programming an inner-loop with `for i in "./keywords.txt"; do ...; done;`

The outer-loop would be the script testing every x seconds if a tab with a blocked title has been opend.

If I want to use more than one keyword

Comment: Does $1 always have id?

Comment: You probably have leading TABs in bt's output. Check $2 instead of $1 but first check $0.

Comment: Shiw us the output of the following command: `bt list | cat -A`

Comment: The most obvious difference between your `grep` command and your `awk` command is that the former searches for pattern `keyword` whereas the latter searches for pattern `keyword:`

Comment: Regarding the `cut` command: `cut -f1` will give you the first field of TAB-separated elements. `cut` defaults to TAB as separator, so you do not need to rely on character ranges.

Comment: @steeldriver: thanks. this was the problem. I took the colon (:) in the linked solution as part of the syntax... now it works

Comment: @Fiximan thanks! very good to know. does cut work with stdout / variables as well or only with files? Or in other words: can I directly pipe the output of a command to cut without the intermediary step of creating a tmp-file? if yes, would you suggest awk or cut for that job?

Comment: @guest_7 I found the solution, but here is the output. does the ^ represent a tab?

`bt list | cat -A
a.1.2^Ishell script - How to awk only output-lines containing a keyword? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange^Ihttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633311/how-to-awk-only-output-lines-containing-a-keyword#comment1185580_633311$
a.1.4^Ibash - How to use 'sed' with piping - Super User^Ihttps://superuser.com/questions/1107680/how-to-use-sed-with-piping$`

Comment: `^I` represents a tab. If you [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input (the output of `bt`) and expected output for the command you want help writing then we can show you how to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: @Josomeister `cut` may as well take input from the pipe. No limitations there.